# Refresh rate of pose of Base Station in OpenVR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, openvr

I am able to get the position of the base stations but this only updates once, while controllers and HDM are constantly updated. Is there a way to force the refresh so that I can get the position of the base stations (trackingreference) in real-time? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically there is, I'm talking driver side right now, but it kinda does nothing, tracking references are normal tracked objects after all so drivers can update their poses like normal with a `vr::VRServerDriverHost()->TrackedDevicePoseUpdated()` call and on init through the pose returned by `GetPose()`

Now, that should work, but it doesnt, even more most of the time custom tracking refences don't show up in SteamVR. what it does under the hood? no idea

Also commercial headsets might update their tracking reference's position only once on startup which seems to be the case